# Components of Vectors

Tags: vectors

My questions have to do with vectors and scalars in general.  However, for ease of communication, I'll craft my questions around the following vector equation:

$$\overrightarrow{r}=x\widehat{i}+y\widehat{j}+z\widehat{k}$$

As I understand it, x, y, and z constitute components.  Are components signed numbers (a.k.a. scalars) or magnitudes (a.k.a. absolute values)?  If the former, what exactly do the signs on these numbers mean?  If the latter, where do the signs on components come from and what exactly do they mean?

Comment: Components, just to confuse things, can be functions, so we can differentiate vectors, turning a position vector into a velocity  vector, for example, so perhaps mathSE is better for this question. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/VectorFunctions.aspx

Comment: Whats the difference between these two? $$ 2 \pmatrix{-1 \\ 0 \\ 0} = (-2) \pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\0}$$

Hint: there isn't. You can interpret the scalar in front of a vector any way you want. It won't change the nature of the problem at hand.

Answer (score 4):

The components are real numbers, and as such they can have either sign. If, for example, $x$ is negative, it means that $\vec r$ points in the direction opposite to $\hat{i}$. You can see this for yourself: work in two dimensions for simplicity (so $\vec r = x \hat i + y \hat j$), and make up a bunch of vectors with different values of $x$ and $y$, including positive, negative, and zero. See what happens.

Comment: Thank you.  Therefore, components are scalars and not magnitudes?  Or, is scalar vs. magnitude an erroneous dichotomy?

Comment: I wouldn't say that vector components are scalars, but I don't want to confuse you with the distinction right now. They are real numbers, tough. And as you say I wouldn't distinguish scalars vs magnitudes; I think of "magnitude" as an operation you can apply to a vector to get a positive number.

Comment: Please say more about the distinction between components and scalars and/or please direct me to a site that does so.  Also, is "magnitude" not an operation that may also be applied to scalars?

Comment: Scalars  (numbers, fields, operators) are things whose value(s) are independent of coordinate system rotations, e.g: $\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r} = x^2+ y^2$. Meanwhile, a component of vector does change. The language from computer science where a scalar is *one* thing, and a vector is *many* has lead to much confusion in BOTH fields.

Comment: Interesting.  So, it appears that signed numbers may or may not constitute scalars.  For example, components of vectors are not scalar because they depend on coordinate system rotations, but work is scalar because it does not depend on such rotations.

Answer (score 1):

You are really asking for the difference between the magnitude and the component of a vector.

The magnitude is always a positive quantity whereas the component can be both negative and positive.

For ease suppose that in one dimension $\vec r=-3 \hat i$

You can interpret this in one of two ways.

$\vec r=(-3) \hat i$ where $-3$ is the component of $\vec r$ in the $\hat i$ direction.

$\vec r=+3 \hat{(-i)}$ where $+3$ is the magnitude of $\vec r$ in the $\hat{(-i)} $ direction where $\hat{(-i)} $ is a unit vector in its own right which happens to be in the opposite direction to unit vector $\vec i$ which you could call $\hat I$.

Note that $\hat I =-1 \hat i$ where unit vector $\hat I$ has a component of $-1$ in the $\hat i$ direction.

You can think of it as once you have chosen a fixed set of reference axes (directions) then then you will use components of the vector in those fixed reference directions to define the vector.

If you choose the magnitude then you will choose the appropriate unit vector to define the vector.

Comment: Not so sure.  See comment by @Countto10.